# cakephp form helper: data not saving

Tags: php, cakephp

I've been playing with CakePHP form helper ([cakephp doc](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)) with some success. Now I'm tring to create a form  located in a view not related to the model of the table. I followed the doc, and put that in my view:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('ApplicationMemberships', array(
'url' => array('controller' => 'ApplicationMemberships', 'action' => 'add'))); ?>
<fieldset >

<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('chantier_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('application_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('ponderation',array('type' => 'number'));
?>

</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

I put this code in the controller to get the data populating the fields:

```
$chantiers = $this->Chantier->find('list');
    $this->loadModel('Application');
    $applications = $this->Application->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('chantiers', 'applications'));
```

Everything went well: I have form, I put some data, then I have a flash saying the data has been saved. Problem: the data has not been added in the database.

---

Edit:

Here is the code doing the saving:

```
    public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->ApplicationMembership->create();
        if ($this->ApplicationMembership->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The application membership has been saved'));
            //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The application membership could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $chantiers = $this->ApplicationMembership->Chantier->find('list');
    $applications = $this->ApplicationMembership->Application->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('chantiers', 'applications'));
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that does the saving?

Comment: Solved. An s in the declaration of the form.

Comment: Thanks for reading my question anyway.

Comment: <?php echo $this->Form->create('ApplicationMemberships', array(
'url' => array('controller' => 'ApplicationMemberships', 'action' => 'add'))); ?>

is wrong because of the extra s in `create('ApplicationMemberships'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was the extra s in `create('ApplicationMemberships')`.

According to the conventions of Cakephp, controllers should be plural and Model singular. So in order to create an instance of the associated model, I should have written:

```
create('ApplicationMembership')
```